# Make express ignore certain URL changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I try to make a Single Page App on Express. The main problem is that I use Express route feature, that re-renders the view each time the URL changes and GET request gets to server. I have a rather usual code like:

```
// Express routes
var routes = {
    index: require('./routes/home')
};
// use routes
app.use('/', routes.index);

//home.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {title: "ITEF"});
});

router.get('/about', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {title: "ITEF"});
});
```

Is there any way to make router ignore URL changes and let the front-side app be as it is? The plan is to buld all UX logic according to URLs, but without countless re-rendering.

Comment: What front end framework are you using? Instead of rendering straight from express server, you can maybe send back res.json with some message in order to inform the front end to do certain task

Comment: Anyway as Express serves the app, it listens to all GET requests and routes them. It seems that the only option is to make two apps - one front-side, another server-side, which is not so good for me

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it's rather easy with `pushState` HTML5 feature:
`window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', '/about');`
Details described in a good article [here](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/).

Answer (score 0):

I little bit late for answering, but I managed to do what you asked using a library called Finch.js.

So, when I want to call another URL in my Single Page Application, I use Finch.navigate('/profile'). The URL will change, and there will be no call to the node server.

```
Finch.route("/profile", function () {
    main.viewModel(new app.model());
});

Finch.listen();

Finch.navigate('/profile');
```

You can learn more about the library here [FINCH](http://rickallen.me/finchjs/)